# Opencart 2.1.0.2 ssl cannot be enabled

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, opencart, opencart2.x

I am experiencing a weird problem on enabling ssl on various opencart installations of 2.1.0.2 version.

I have a VPS that has SSL via the new cpanel to all acounts available.

I have already enabled ssl and https on many opencart 1.5 versions, wordpress and even old joomla accounts.

However when i try to enable https on any opencart 2.1.0.2 version via the following procedure i get a bizarre redirection to a suspended account of my vps.

The procedure i follow for ssl in opencart 2.1.0.2 is:

I edit the config.php files both at public_html and admin to

```
 // HTTPS
 define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/admin/');
 define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://example.com/');
```

I enable ssl via the backend server settings in opencart

and i add in my .htacces file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

right after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

I even tried to force https to all links in config files as:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://example.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://example.com/');
```

with no luck.

Any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before you add any configuration changes, visit your site:
https://example.com/

If you still get the weird, unexpected page - contact your host, as there's no change in OpenCart you can do to fix a server misconfiguration.

With that said, how did you "enable" SSL?  Via Let's Encrypt or a purchased SSL?  If you only added the https to your config files, you do not have any SSL enabled.  Your host may 'offer' it, but it may not exist by default.

If your host offers it via your cPanel, install a free SSL via the Let's Encrypt cPanel plugin.  It should be done automatically and only take a few seconds to complete and you would receive a success message once it's been installed and activated to your site.